# How to fetch Updated values from Ignite Cache?

Tags: scala, caching, ignite, in-memory

I have an ignite cache, in which data is continuously inserting. Is there any method for getting only updated values from the cache? I need to insert this data into Hive without duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignite basically has three strategies to deal with it: Continuous Queries, Cache Store and [Cache Events](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/events#igniteevents-api).

It seems from your description that [Continuous Query](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries) fits you best, however please note there may be tiny overlap between Initial Query and first callbacks to handler.

Otherwise, if you want to have Ignite in sync with Hive always, [Cache Store](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store) with Write Through is your best friend.

Comment: Is there any example in scala?

Comment: @Ashokv There are Java examples bundled with Ignite, converting them to Scala should not be very hard.